# How to argue this integral over this semicircle vanishes as $R\to \infty$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I want to evaluate the inverse Laplace transform of the function $$F(s)=\frac{A(s)}{B(s)},\quad B(s)=(s-s_1)\cdots (s-s_n),\quad s_i\neq s_j,\forall i\ne j.$$

I want to use the inversion formula together with contour integration. My starting point is the inversion formula $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}[F(s)]=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}e^{st}F(s)ds,$$

where $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ is any number so that all singularities of $F(s)$ lie to its left in the complex plane.

In that case, assuming $A(s)$ has no singularities, the singularities are exactly $\{s_i\}$, so we take any $\gamma > \max \{\operatorname{Re}(s_i)\}$.

Next, I consider a contour $\Gamma$ made up of two pieces:

1. $C_1(T)$: a vertical line $z(\lambda)=\gamma+i\lambda$ for $\lambda \in [-T,T]$. As $T\to \infty$ this one gives what we need.
2. $C_2(T,R)$: a semicircle starting at $\gamma+iT$ and ending at $\gamma - iT$.

We then have set $$g(z)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}e^{zt}F(z).$$ We then have

$$\int_{C_1(T)} g(z)dz = \oint_{\Gamma}g(z)dz-\int_{C_2(T,R)}g(z)dz.$$

The integral over the closed contour can be done with the residue theorem. My issue is the last integral. We must take $T,R\to \infty$ but for the Laplace transform I don't see how to proceed.

I mean, I have the intuition. Call $z = x+iy$, along $C_2(T,R)$ if $R\to \infty$, then $x\to -\infty$. Then $e^{zt} = e^{xt}e^{iyt}\to 0$ as $R\to \infty$, so it should make the integral decay as well. But that is not really rigorous.

So how can I proceed here and show the integral on the semicircle $C_2(T,R)$ vanishes as $T,R\to \infty$?

Comment: I guess your semicircle is centered at $z=\gamma$ and its radius is $T$, right? What do you need $R$ for?

Comment: @GReyes, in fact it is not. Take a look at this question of mine https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370816/parameterizing-the-bromwich-contour/3370827#3370827. We *could* make it centered at the origin, but then you have to parameterize it as $z = \gamma + Re^{i\theta}$. The parameterization $z = Re^{i\theta}$ is for a circle centered at the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that

$$\left | \int_{C_2(T,R)} dz \, e^{z t} F(z) \right | \to 0$$

as $R \to \infty$.  On $C_2(T,R)$, $\left | e^{z t} \right | = e^{R t \cos{\theta}}$ where $\theta \in [\pi/2, 3 \pi/2]$.  Thus, the integral is bounded by

$$\begin{align} \max_{\theta \in [\pi/2, 3 \pi/2]} \left | F \left ( R e^{i \theta} \right ) \right | \int_{\pi/2}^{3 \pi/2} d\theta \,  e^{R t \cos{\theta}} & = \max_{\theta \in [\pi/2, 3 \pi/2]} \left | F \left ( R e^{i \theta} \right ) \right | \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \,  e^{-R t \sin{\theta}} \\ &= 2 \max_{\theta \in [\pi/2, 3 \pi/2]} \left | F \left ( R e^{i \theta} \right ) \right | \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \,  e^{-R t \sin{\theta}} \\ &\le 2 \max_{\theta \in [\pi/2, 3 \pi/2]} \left | F \left ( R e^{i \theta} \right ) \right | \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \,  e^{-2 R t \theta/ \pi} \\ &\le \frac{\pi}{R t} \max_{\theta \in [\pi/2, 3 \pi/2]} \left | F \left ( R e^{i \theta} \right ) \right | \end{align}$$

As long as $\max_{\theta \in [\pi/2, 3 \pi/2]} \left | F \left ( R e^{i \theta} \right ) \right | = o(R)$ as $R \to \infty$, then the integral over $C_2(T,R)$ vanishes in this limit.

Comment: Thanks @RonGordon. About the last argument, checking if I got it right. If the maximum $M = o(R)$ as $R\to \infty$ then for any constant $\kappa$ there is $R_0$ so that $R > R_0$ implies $M < \kappa R$. Then let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, using $\kappa = t\epsilon/\pi$ we get such $R_0$ and this implies that if $R > R_0$ we shall have (calling the integral $I$): $$|I(R)|\leq \frac{\pi}{Rt}M<\frac{\pi}{Rt}\frac{t\epsilon}{\pi}=\epsilon$$
Thereby showing that $I(R)\to 0$ as $R\to \infty$. I got it right?

Comment: @user1620696: Yes, I think that about sums it up.

Comment: Just one more point I noticed right now and got confused. In the very first line it seems you are changing variables $\theta' = \theta - \pi/2$. The interval gets mapped to $[0,\pi]$ but $\cos\theta = \cos(\theta' + \pi/2) = -\sin\theta$. But if that happens, then from the second to third line, $\sin\theta \leq \theta$ gets reversed right $-\sin\theta \geq -\theta$. So what happened to this sign?

Comment: @user1620696: good catch - it is negative.  Otherwise the last approximation would not make any sense!